# Kivy .kv file use function defined in outside file

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

3 files. test.py, myfunctions.py & test.kv

trying to call a function from myfunctions.py in the test.kv

test.py

```
from kivy.app import App
import myfunctions

class TestApp(App):
    title = 'Test Application'
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

myfunctions.py

```
def myfunc():
    print('hello world')
```

test.kv

```
GridLayout:
    Button:
        text: "My Button"
        on_release: myfunc()
```

I have also tried defining the function inside the app class(per the kivy documentation) - didn't work

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [the docs](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#special-syntaxes) point out, you have to import the function in the .kv:

```
#:import myfunc myfunctions.myfunc

GridLayout:
    Button:
        text: "My Button"
        on_release: myfunc()
```

Comment: i see, i did ... #:import f1 myfunctions

Comment: @ZacharySutton So if my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, check the [tour], that's the best way to thank.